# Photoshop picture inside another?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If you've seen the Style music video by Taylor Swift I wanna know how can I do the effect where smoke is fading inside her body in photoshop. I am creating an ad and it I wanted to do the same but with a dress. Here's a photos to show what I mean. 
How can I do that on photoshop?[image]

Comment: Hi Dana, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: You use Masks..

Comment: Or it could just be a blending mode

Answer (score 7):

I used `Blending Modes` and got this in about 2 minutes...

[image: base]

I added a picture of smoke that I found on Google - **a black background is critical!**

[image: smoke]

Changed the smoke's `Blending Mode` to `Screen`

[image: screen]

Voila!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

USE Clip Masking for this as :

1. Select the image with quick selection tool and copy of image as ctrl J

[image: image of Selection tool]

2.Next Put the cloud image and go to the layer menu and click create clip masking as layer>create clipping masking and get the result

[image: image of clipping masking]